# MouseKeyHook "strong name required"

Tags: c#, strongname, mousekeyhook

I implemented an application which uses the Nuget package MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor. Everything was working fine so far. I now wanted to build a Setup Project to deploy the application on other computers. Therefore I had to sign my project. Since then I cannot built the project anymore as it says (Translation from German to English):

> "The file or assembly 'MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor ...' or a
>   dependancy was not found. An assembly with a strong name is required.
>   (xception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)".

Does anybody have an idea how to give this third party package a strong name so I can built the project again?

Comment: You most likely have to rebuild it from the source, specifying either late signing or a signing key to use.

Comment: Just download the [github source](https://github.com/katopz/oskz-vcsharp/tree/master/MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor) and add your own strong name.

Comment: or look at the answer to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58980683/how-to-resolve-error-msb3188-assembly-must-be-strong-signed-in-order-to-be  I think it shows a better way (Reference to DLL instead of PackageReference).